# How to uninitialize/undefine a variable in Ruby so I don't get warnings in console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, initialization

I keep getting this warning in console, it's cluttering my `puts` output, and I want it gone:

```
d.rb:24: warning: previous definition of VariableA was here
d.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant VariableA
```

Tried doing this after using them:

```
VariableA = nil
VariableB = nil
```

Important note: These variables are re-used in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby whenever you use a capital letter first letter you are creating a constant. You will be warned when it is redefined.

For example

```
class
  THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT = 42
  ThisIsAlsoAConstant = "The answer!"

  @@this_is_a_class_variable

  def a_method
   @this_is_a_member_variable = true
   this_is_a_local_variable = true
  end

end
```

If you create a constant inside a method, you will get re-definition error the second time you call the method.

Answer (score 3):

As zhon points out, you are actually creating a constant.  The `defined?` keyword demonstrates this:

```
local_var = "foo"
some_constant = "bar"
Local_var = "foo"
SOME_CONSTAT = "baz"

puts defined? local_var                 #=> local-variable
puts defined? some_constant             #=> local-variable
puts defined? Local_var                 #=> constant
puts defined? SOME_CONSTAT              #=> constant
```

However, you shouldn't create initially-capitalized constants.  The convention is to use [`SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case).